# Other ways to say "I have a bad hunch"

Tags: phrases, idioms, synonyms

I'm looking for ways to say "I'm having a bad hunch", or more like a bad feeling about something upcoming. The gut-wrenching feeling that something bad will happen.

Comment: "My spidey sense tells me..."

Comment: I've got a bad feeling about this, Scoob...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[fore·bod·ing](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/foreboding):

*noun* - fearful apprehension; a feeling that something bad will happen:

> with a sense of foreboding she read the note

*adjective* - implying or seeming to imply that something bad is going to happen:

> when the doctor spoke, his voice was dark and foreboding

Synonyms: apprehension, anxiety, trepidation, disquiet, unease, uneasiness, misgiving, worry, fear, fearfulness, dread

Answer (score 15):

> I've got a baaad feeling about this.

(Note that this does have a [certain pop-culture reference](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Drkh0YLF8rI)...)

Comment: Came here to post this. +1 to you sir.

Comment: The OP already knows this expression, it's in the question itself.

Comment: @Mari-LouA no, the question mentions a (semantically equivalent) expression, that is lacking the pop-culture weight.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, the three "a"s do make all the difference.

Comment: @Mari-LouA hehe, I am honestly not sure if you are being serious or sarcastic :-)

Comment: Grudgingly, I admit, the link is fun :)

Comment: Just found the canonical reference for this: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/I_have_a_bad_feeling_about_this

Answer (score 10):

Consider **[premonition](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/premonition)**

> an intuition of a future, usually unwelcome, occurrence; foreboding

Also

> - forboding
> - dread
> - apprehension
> - presage
> - shadow
> - feeling in his bones

Answer (score 8):

***ominous***

> 1. giving the impression that something bad or unpleasant is going to happen; threatening; inauspicious.

Excerpt from [The Woman in White](http://books.google.it/books?id=YH4U8oIPdj4C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=ominous&f=false) *by Wilkie Collins*

> I felt the ominous future coming close, chilling me with an
> unutterable awe, forcing on me the conviction of an unseen design in
> the long series of complications which had now fastened round us. I
> thought of Hartright--as I saw him in the body when he said farewell;
> as I saw him in the spirit in my dream--and I too began to doubt now
> whether we were not advancing blindfold to an appointed and an
> inevitable end.

Answer (score 1):

I was just about to suggest expressing it with reference to your '**doomdar**', as in radar, gaydar, etc. I'd never heard the term before, and decided to [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=doomdar&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb) (always a good idea before claiming a neologism, especially when it seems so obvious.) The search brings back about 8300 results, very few of them actually finding the the word *as* a word, in the sense I'm suggesting it. But the very first hit goes to the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=DoomDar), where the word is defined in terms very close to the OP's original question.

> The innate intuition of impending Doom that a person feels before the
>   Event of Doom actually occurs. Operates at the same intuitive level as
>   GayDar and GameDar.

The word comes up a [complete blank](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=doomdar&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) at the nGram viewer: "No valid ngrams to plot!"

So in use, it would be something like: *This [situation] is tripping my doomdar.*

Note: I'm not citing the UD as an authority, just as evidence that the word does make intuitive sense. Whether it would be appropriate in any given context is another story.

Answer (score 0):

'I am picking up bad "vibes" on that subject/ on that individual etc'.

Answer (score 0):

You could try, "I felt a sense of dread."