# I’m looking for a word or phrase that describes the feeling that something very bad or catastrophic is about to happen

Tags: phrases, expressions

It may be something that will happen to the person who is having the feeling but it may also be to several persons, as might occur with a highly destructive earthquake, for instance.

The word or phrase would be used in the following sentence:

> “I’m no spiritualist but I have a feeling of ___. I hope it’s just a feeling."

EDIT - The phrase I'm looking for conveys a much stronger feeling than "I have a bad hunch". It is about something **catastrophic** which the person feels is "going to happen in a few minutes".

Comment: ... of dread / great apprehension.

Comment: a disturbance in the Force?

Comment: I think this is Primarily Opinion-based. There are any number of credible words, including *angst, fear, dread, trepidation, foreboding, unease,* etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Other ways to say "I have a bad hunch"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132438/other-ways-to-say-i-have-a-bad-hunch) and also related: [Vocabulary: an event, usually an unplesant one, that might or might not happen](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143181/vocabulary-an-event-usually-an-unplesant-one-that-might-or-might-not-happen)

Comment: Most people go with "I have a bad feeling". Usually others know that to mean they feel as if something bad is going to happen and not that they are hungry or sad or something

Comment: ca·lam·i·ty would best fit the feeling

Comment: @unixmiah: "calamity" refers to an event, not a feeling

Comment: "By the pricking of my thumbs, something wicked this way comes." [Macbeth, Act 4, scene 1, ll. 44-45](http://www.enotes.com/shakespeare-quotes/by-pricking-my-thumbs)

Comment: @Mari-LouA The phrase I'm looking for conveys a much stronger feeling than "I have a bad hunch". It is about something catastrophic which is felt as "going to happen in a few minutes".

Comment: A bad feeling is still a hunch, whether the catastrophe that is about to befall is verified or not, regardless of how strongly  this "feeling" is felt, and if it's prompted by a sense of unease or by mere superstition. The top score is the same one in the dupe because it doesn't matter how imminent that event might be, the feeling suscitated is the same.

Comment: What happened to good old fashioned fear.

Comment: @marsh "fear" is general, not specifically "about to happen".

Comment: @Lohoris I usually don't 'answer' single word requests which I feel are readily answerable by thinking of one possibility and then checking in a thesaurus. 'Dread' is hardly an obscure word.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth it's not an obscure word, but searching for a word if you know its meaning is definitely much more difficult than just searching for the meaning of a word…

Answer (score 27, accepted):

My first thoughts on reading the question were of the phrase 'I have a feeling of **impending doom**.' Since the word 'catastrophic' is used, this doesn't feel unduly strong.

**Edit** by Centaurus - I'm adding some lines from [**the reference**](http://www.anxietycentre.com/anxiety-symptoms/fear-of-impending-doom.shtml) the answerer has given in his comment below:

> Many people experience strong feelings and sensations associated with fear and anxiety. They are especially powerful when they occur for seemingly no reason. Consequently, many people react to these "out of the blue" feelings with fear, which only serves to inflame them. To better understand these strong **impending doom** feelings, the anxiety symptom **“fear of impending doom” is often described as one or many of the following:**
>
> - Feeling like something awful is about to occur
> - A sense that something very dangerous is about to happen
> - An overwhelming feeling you are about to die
> - A strong feeling that something terrible is about to happen and there isn’t anything you can do about it
> - A strong feeling of death and destruction that suddenly comes over you
> - An overwhelming fear of impending doom, destruction, despair, and gloom
> - A horrible feeling of doom and gloom that washes over you
> - Fear of impending doom that begins or accompanies a panic attack or anxiety attack
> - Such a strong feeling of impending doom that you feel you have to escape immediately or something terrible will happen

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  Thank you. Could you expand and add definition and link?

Comment: Beyond it's general sense, this is the most common term in the medical literature, e.g., as a potential symptom [of a heart attack](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/imagepages/19191.htm) or [of panic disorders](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/000924.htm).

Comment: Apologies fir late reply @Centaurus. I am no expert, merely an habitual user of British English! This link may be useful http://www.anxietycentre.com/anxiety-symptoms/fear-of-impending-doom.shtml

Comment: I had the same first thought. Maybe because of its occurance in Dilbert comics/videogame? http://search.dilbert.com/comic/Impending%20Doom

Answer (score 60):

How about [foreboding](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/foreboding): 'a strong inner feeling or notion of a future misfortune, evil, etc'.

Comment: +1! How would one use _foreboding_ as in the OP's example? "I feel a foreboding," perhaps?

Comment: "I have a sense of foreboding."  Or, if it's really bad, "I have a sense of five-boding."  (A running joke with my wife.)

Comment: The expression I'm looking for would fill the blanks here: I'm no spiritualist but I have a feeling of ----------------.

Comment: @Centaurus -- "I have a feeling of foreboding" is a perfectly good way to use the word.  (Though "sense of foreboding" sounds more, well, foreboding.)

Comment: If FumbleFingers' comment (mentioninf 'foreboding') preceded this answer, I feel the enormous upvote tally is even less appropriate.

Answer (score 29):

Is not the word you are searching ***ominous***?

*I'm no spiritualist but I have an **ominous** feeling, ...*.

Equally, as Patrick Wood points out a ***feeling of foreboding*** would do equally well, perhaps engendering even more concern in the listener.

Comment: I don't think one has an "ominous feeling", one has a negative feeling in response to an *ominous situation*. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ominous

Comment: The expression I'm looking for would fill the blanks here: I'm no spiritualist but I have a feeling of ----------------.

Comment: @DigitalChris I have thought about this matter carefully. Since *ominous* (from *omen*) is an adjective and 'feelings* a noun, it must be possible for there to be *ominous feelings*.  Certainly if I have a strange feeling in my stomach, it could be an *ominous* sign of food poisoning. Feelings and sensibilities of a less physical kind, can act as a barometer of likely events. It would seem to me, therefore, that they can be *ominous*. Though I would agree that the more usual expression is of worries about *ominous signs*.

Comment: @Centaurus You could have a 'feeling of ill omen', which is otherwise put as 'an ominous feeling'.

Comment: *ominous feeling* sounds perfectly natural to me, and would substitute into @Centaurus' sentence, probably with an extra adverbial phrase at the end: "I'm no spiritualist, but I have an ominous feeling about this." or "I'm no spiritualist, but I have an ominous feeling right now."

Answer (score 11):

> I’m no spiritualist but I have a **premonition**. I hope it’s no more than that.

The alternative shown above may work.  From [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/premonition#Noun), *premonition* means

> (1) A clairvoyant or clairaudient experience, such as a dream, which resonates with some event in the future.
>   (2) A strong intuition that something is about to happen (usually something negative, but not exclusively).

Comment: Premonition has no negative connotations. A premonition could be good or bad.

Comment: @DaveMagner, Wiktionary suggests it's usually something negative; which in fact is a negative connotation.  But perhaps it doesn't have a negative denotation.

Comment: The OED definition is "The action of premonishing or forewarning; a previous notification or warning of subsequent events; a forewarning." I think there is almost nothing in any of these definitions (except the questionable Wiktionary) which suggests the event must be negative; however, I would agree that the word is usually used when something negative is or has been suspected.

Comment: @Dave - NOAD's defintion reads: "a strong feeling that something is about to happen, **esp. something unpleasant** : *he had a premonition of imminent disaster*" [emphasis added]. When I Google `"he had a premonition that"`, the results are filled with premonitions of plane crashes, chainsaw accidents, and death. Maybe there's a premonition of winning the lottery buried in there somewhere, but I'd say that _premonition_ at least leans toward the negative, even if it can be used both ways.

Answer (score 5):

I have a feeling of impending danger or I have a presentiment of impending danger.

Answer (score 4):

[Presage](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/presage?q=Presage):

> - a  sign that something, often something unpleasant, will happen:
> - something that foreshadows or portends a future event , omen
>
>   - The fact that no agreement has been reached by the Prime Ministers  is a presage that a conflict  may be imminent.

(from www.dictionary.cambridge.org)

Answer (score 1):

The word apprehension comes to mind.

Comment: Your post would be improved if it included a reference and an explanation of why it answers the question.

Comment: Agree with @andy - in its current form, this makes a better comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect opportunity to use one of my favorite words:

**[consternation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/consternation)** - noun - "An emotion experienced in anticipation of some specific pain or danger."

Comment: The first definition on Webster's site is "a strong feeling of surprise or sudden disappointment that causes confusion", and that's closer to my understanding.  "Consternation" is something you experience *after* an event.

Comment: This is a good point, that it may be used "after the fact." The OED definition is "Amazement and terror such as to prostrate one's faculties; dismay." There is nothing to suggest that it is a feeling that can only occur after an event. However, it does describe a judgement about an event, actual or potential, and thus does not precisely apply to the feeling in question (for which "apprehension" is an excellent term).

Answer (score 0):

"I felt the hair on the back of my neck stand up"

Comment: That could be a statement indicating general eeriness or even fright from a situation and is not usually or specifically linked to the sometimes unexplainable feeling that something bad will happen

Comment: Maybe you're  not frightened by sensing something bad happening, but I am!

Answer (score 0):

"I feel like someone just walked over my grave" is a dark, ominous, foreboding description, and it hints toward death with a touch of the supernatural.

Comment: This refers to an eerie sensation, but not specifically to a feeling that something bad is about to happen. It is ominous, but rarely used to express feelings of foreboding