# Word to describe the state of "nothing bad happening"

Tags: single-word-requests

Essentially I'm looking for the opposite of [foreboding](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/214381/i-m-looking-for-a-word-or-phrase-that-describes-the-feeling-that-something-very).

Specifically to describe the state of nothing bad happening (no worries) – everything being reasonably good (feeling generally good), especially after bad things having happened in the recent past.

Comment: I would like to see an example sentence with a blank where the desired word would go.  I have some additional ideas, but I want to try to fit into the way of using the word that you have in mind.

Comment: @aparente001 well, how about: "I've been feeling ___ for the past week" implying that i have not been worrying about anything (no fearful apprehension) and that during all of those days I "felt fine," being content with how (nearly) each and every moment unfolded (no resentment of past or fear of future). Does that give you enough context?

Comment: "I've been feeling **relaxed** for the past week." You may also use **free of concern** (or *carefree* mentionned by @apparente001) as an adjective, e.g. *I would like you to be free from concern*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the adjective *copacetic* (also *copasetic* or *copesetic*), e.g., "*everything seems copacetic for the foreseeable future*"

> [**copacetic**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/copacetic) *adjective*: very satisfactory; "*don't worry, because I assure you that everything's copacetic*"
>
> **Synonyms**: agreeable, all right, alright, satisfactory, ducky, fine, good, hunky-dory, jake [slang], OK (or okay), palatable;
>
> **Antonyms**: disagreeable, unsatisfactory (Merriam-Webster online)
>
> **Etymology**: 1919, but it may have origins in 19c. U.S. Southern black speech. Origin unknown, suspects include Latin, Yiddish (Hebrew *kol b'seder*), Italian, Louisiana French (*coupe-sétique*), and Native American. None is considered convincing by linguists. [**etymonline**](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=copacetic&searchmode=nl)

Comment: Interesting word. More on its etymology here: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/copacetic#Etymology

Answer (score 1):

For substitution of foreboding, I have used results from [Just The Word](http://www.just-the-word.com/main.pl?word=foreboding&mode=combinations#N%20PREP%20N*) (which uses the [British National Corpus](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/)) to find some common use of the word and come up with suggestions for the opposite of:

- a sense of foreboding
- filled with foreboding

Instead of having a sense of foreboding, one may have a sense of [security](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/security) (nothing bad is going to happen).

When one is filled with foreboding they dread the future so one might be filled with [anticipation](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/security) when they look forward to it (feeling good).

Comment: I suppose 'feeling secure' is a reasonable answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Placid.**  Also **tranquil** and **recollected**.

From Merriam-Webster online:

[placid](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/placid)

> : not easily upset or excited
>
> : not moving much : calm and steady
>
> : serenely free of interruption or disturbance
>
> Synonyms:
>     collected, composed, cool, coolheaded, equal, level, limpid, peaceful, calm, possessed, recollected, sedate, self-composed, self-possessed, serene, smooth, together, tranquil, undisturbed, unperturbed, unruffled, unshaken, untroubled, unworried
>
> Antonyms:
>     agitated, discomposed, disturbed, flustered, perturbed, unglued, unhinged, unstrung, upset

Comment: Hmm, "placid" has certain restrictions. If I'm excited about something, it won't be captured by "placid" - whereas the state of "nothing bad [currently] happening" doesn't necessarily preclude "something good/great [currently] happening".

Answer (score 0):

> 'I've been feeling ___ for the past week" implying that i have not
>   been worrying about anything (no fearful apprehension) and that during
>   all of those days I "felt fine," being content with how (nearly) each
>   and every moment unfolded (no resentment of past or fear of future).'

**easy in my mind** ("untroubled, contented, relaxed, satisfied, calm, peaceful, serene, tranquil, quiet, undisturbed, unworried: *I was not altogether easy in my mind about this decision.*" -- Collins Thesaurus)

Also possible:

*carefree*

*happy-go-lucky*

*laid back*