# Idiom for premonition

Tags: idioms, american-english, british-english, idiom-requests, north-american-english

I am trying to remember an idiom that is used when someone has a premonition about something, often coincidentally i.e. I am thinking about someone and then they call me. I know there is the expression: speak of the devil, but I think there is another less-commonly used idiom which can be more broadly applied. As I remember it is also not used directly like speak of the devil but more to say someone has summoned someone/something else.

EDIT: Apparently speak of the devil is not used in a negative sense. Thanks  user240918 for the correction.

Comment: “Speak of the devil” has no negative connotation. https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/talk-speak-of-the-devil

Comment: Learn something new everyday. Thanks! Have updated the original post.

Comment: @user240918 It sure feels negative if you're the one they're talking about.

Comment: 'Precognition' is a sci-fi word for seeing into the future. It's not an actual thing.

Comment: Ok. Yeah was thinking like ESP from star trek, but I agree with your edit. Am not looking for a scifi idiom - though not sure if one would exist.

Comment: Possibly related [1. Something bad about to happen](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/214381/i-m-looking-for-a-word-or-phrase-that-describes-the-feeling-that-something-very). [2. Impending doom](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/214381/i-m-looking-for-a-word-or-phrase-that-describes-the-feeling-that-something-very).

Answer (score 1):

I found another **often used phrase** that can be considered an **idiom**. You could use the idiom "**sixth sense**". It is often used to describe a mysterious, coincidental ability that goes beyond the usual five senses. Having premonitions is frequently the case with this ability. Here is an example.

> She said "maybe you'll get a call"... and Wow! Suddenly the phone
>   rang... Can you believe it?  She sure does have a **sixth sense** at times.

https://www.powerthesaurus.org/premonition/synonyms/idiom

Answer (score 0):

***[Ears are burning](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ears%20are%20burning)*** is probably what you are looking for:

> — used to say that someone has the feeling that other people are talking about him or her.

(M-W)

Comment: Thanks. Was looking for an expression that is more commonly used in third person. Like Bob summoned Joe by __.

Comment: @NealKornreich - If you have a sentence you want the phrase to fit into, edit that phrase into your question.

Answer (score 0):

The word [premonition](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/premonition) itself is usually (**but not always**) associated with foreseeing a negative event.

So,

You could use the idiom "**writing on the wall**"to describe such a mysterious, coincidental, precognitive event. Here is an example.

> She said "maybe you'll get a call"... and Wow! Suddenly the phone
>   rings.... She sure can see the [writing on the wall](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/writing+on+the+wall) sometimes.

Comment: "*writing on the wall*" does **not** describe premonition. It refers to warning signs that can be seen clearly, if you pay attention.

Comment: If you say so, but as an idiom it can loosely refer to a prediction of the future that comes true.  It is much like the reading of tea leaves. Please do pay attention now.

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/the-writing-is-on-the-wall Note the *"clear signs"* part.

Comment: Jinx! you owe me a coke.

Comment: And also https://www.powerthesaurus.org/premonition/synonyms/idiom

Answer (score 0):

You might consider, ***speak of angels and you hear the rustle of their wings***; also: *speak of angels and you hear rustling of their wings*; *speak of the angels and you will hear their wings rustle*; *speak of an angel, hear the rustle of its wing*; *speak of an angel and you can hear bats' wings flutter*.

> > *As we have said in the previous chapter, the general public is gradually awakening to the knowledge of the reality of Mental Transference, and it is scarcely necessary to devote the time and space to a proof of the reality of the phenomena in these days, although a few years ago a work on the subject would have had to be composed principally of evidences and proofs. But, nevertheless, it may be well for us to take a hasty look at the nature of the proof in this work.*
> >
> > *Nearly everyone has had evidence of Mind Reading or Thought Transference in his or her own life. Nearly everyone has had experiences of being in a persons company when one of the two would make a remark and the other somewhat startled, would exclaim, "Why, that's just what I was going to say," or words to that effect. Nearly everyone has had experiences of knowing what a second person was going to say before the person spoke. And, likewise common is the experience of thinking of a person a few moments before the person came into sight. Many of us have suddenly found ourselves thinking of a person who had been out of our minds for months, or years, when all of a sudden the person himself would appear. These instances are so common as to be generally recognized without question. **These occurrences have given rise to the two common "sayings," viz., "Speak of the devil and his imps appear," or "Speak of angels and you hear the rustle of their wings."***

Sources:

- [Practical Mind-Reading: A Course of Lessons on Thought Transference by William Walker Atkinson](https://books.google.fr/books?id=jw8d3PRYvSUC&pg=PA14&dq="speak+of+angels+and+you"&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjThtfovezdAhUJyxoKHREQDToQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=%22speak%20of%20angels%20and%20you%22&f=false).
- [The Frank C. Brown Collection of North Carolina Folklore: Games and Rhymes. Beliefs and Customs. Riddles. Proverbs. Speech. Tales and Legends - Duke University Press, 1952](https://archive.org/details/frankcbrowncolle00fran/page/n0).